# Why does KNN Model return 99% accuracy on dataset with default parameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I am building a model that predicts if a user will like a stock or not based on different features, such as Market Cap, Current Ratio, Sector, Trailing PE, etc. I am going to implement this model in a website, where the model is able to adapt over time to user preferences. I made an example dataset that generally represents how the data that gets passed to the model will look. I have build a KNN model based on that sample dataset, and I get 99% accuracy on the training split and test split. I also get 98%-99% on my classification report even though I have class imbalance, about 500 of one class, and 10500 of another class. My macro average and weighted average are both 99%. I was planning on optimizing this model by hyper tuning, but does anyone know why I got 99% accuracy immediately?

Comment: Did you try to visualize the result? It was possibly caused by either overfit or underfit. However, there is another community for artificial intelligence topics. You can ask this question [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Coderio how would I visualize it?

Comment: This sounds like an ML question, not a programming question -- you should probably ask on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) or one of the other Stack Exchanges. But either way, we need to see a minimal version of your code. My first Q is how exactly did you split the data? If the data is not IID, and it sounds like it's not, then you cannot split randomly (e.g. with `train_test_split()`).